Delete indexed observation based on other column entry
I have an example imported excel spreadsheet that appears like this with many more entries and i read in with pd.read_excel.  I would like to delete all of ID 3's entries since the status is deleted and I would like to remove the whole index 7 since the region is not set.  I started off by setting a mulit index with df = df.set_index(['id']), I then performed this df.set_index('id')[['status']].eq('deleted').groupby(level=0).all()
and got the True/False value results with an extra false in the row above the first entry.  Unsure how to perform the delete row if region mission.
    id  name    status  region  category
0   1   foo             north   a
1                       east    a
2                       west    a
3                       south   a
4   2   bar             north   b
5                       east    b
6                       west    b
7                               b
8   3   baz    deleted  north   c
9                       east    c
10                      west    c
11                      south   c
12  4   buz             north   d
13                      east    d
14                      west    d
15                      south   d


results
    status
id  
    False
1   False
2   False
3   True
4   False


would like results to end up like this based on status and missing region entry.  The sequential 0-15 column was just me typing and not necessarily part of result needed.
    id  name    status  region  category
0   1   foo             north   a
1                       east    a
2                       west    a
3                       south   a
4   2   bar             north   b
5                       east    b
6                       west    b
12  4   buz             north   d
13                      east    d
14                      west    d
15                      south   d


Here is a dictionary that represents the data
data = {'id': {0: '1',1: '',2: '', 3: '', 4: '2', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '3', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '4', 13: '', 14: '', 15: ''},
 'name': {0: 'foo', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: 'bar', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: 'baz', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: 'buz', 13: '', 14: '', 15: ''},
 'status': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: 'deleted', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: ''},
 'region': {0: 'north', 1: 'east', 2: 'west', 3: 'south', 4: 'north', 5: 'east', 6: 'west', 7: '', 8: 'north', 9: 'east', 10: 'west', 11: 'south', 12: 'north', 13: 'east', 14: 'west', 15: 'south'},
 'category': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b', 7: 'b', 8: 'c', 9: 'c', 10: 'c', 11: 'c', 12: 'd', 13: 'd', 14: 'd', 15: 'd'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)



can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

added edit to my entry above

# Put 'ok' in status column if it is not 'deleted'. Only in the 1st row as for 'deleted'
df['status'] = np.where((df['name'] != '') & (df['status'] != "deleted"), 'ok', df['status'])
# Fill in status column according to the value on the row above 
df['status'] = df['status'].replace('', np.nan).fillna(method='ffill')

# Remove the rows where the status is 'deleted'
df = df.drop(index=df[df['status'] == 'deleted'].index)
# Remove the rows where there is no region
df = df.drop(index=df[df['region'] == ''].index)
# Rplace the 'ok' status by an empty string as in the original df
df['status'] = df['status'].replace('ok', '')
display(df)



You can perform boolean indexing with masks and groupby.transform:
# does the row have a valid region?
m1 = df['region'].ne('')
# if the row/group not deleted?
m2 = df['status'].ne('deleted')

# keep the rows with valid region
# and not belonging to an id with a deleted status
out = df.loc[m1 & m2.groupby(df['id'].replace('', None).ffill())
                    .transform('all')]

Output:
   id name status region category
0   1  foo         north        a
1                   east        a
2                   west        a
3                  south        a
4   2  bar         north        b
5                   east        b
6                   west        b
12  4  buz         north        d
13                  east        d
14                  west        d
15                 south        d

Intermediates:
   id name   status region category     m1     m2 ffilled_id  m2(all)  m1 & m2(all)
0   1  foo           north        a   True   True          1     True          True
1                     east        a   True   True          1     True          True
2                     west        a   True   True          1     True          True
3                    south        a   True   True          1     True          True
4   2  bar           north        b   True   True          2     True          True
5                     east        b   True   True          2     True          True
6                     west        b   True   True          2     True          True
7                                 b  False   True          2     True         False
8   3  baz  deleted  north        c   True  False          3    False         False
9                     east        c   True   True          3    False         False
10                    west        c   True   True          3    False         False
11                   south        c   True   True          3    False         False
12  4  buz           north        d   True   True          4     True          True
13                    east        d   True   True          4     True          True
14                    west        d   True   True          4     True          True
15                   south        d   True   True          4     True          True


